# How can I get a SQL Query from wordpress tables

Tags: mysql, sql, wordpress

I have a sql query and don't find the right solution.

The query works, but it doesn't show me the columns of the `wp_usermeta` table, only the columns of the `wp_users` are shown.

If I delete the `where` clause, all lines with all values of the columns are shown, but I need only the lines depending on the `meta_value = "Prod"` from the column meta.key = 'kennung_produzent'

```
SELECT p.ID,
       p.user_login,
       p.user_registered,
       p.display_name,
        max( CASE WHEN pm.meta_key = 'nickname' and p.ID = pm.user_id THEN pm.meta_value END ) as Nickname,
        max( CASE WHEN pm.meta_key = 'billing_email' and p.ID = pm.user_id THEN pm.meta_value END ) as email,
        max( CASE WHEN pm.meta_key = 'billing_first_name' and p.ID = pm.user_id THEN pm.meta_value END ) as Vorname,
        max( CASE WHEN pm.meta_key = 'billing_last_name' and p.ID = pm.user_id THEN pm.meta_value END ) as Nachname,
        max( CASE WHEN pm.meta_key = 'billing_phone' and p.ID = pm.user_id THEN pm.meta_value END ) as Telefon,
        max( CASE WHEN pm.meta_key = 'billing_postcode' and p.ID = pm.user_id THEN pm.meta_value END ) as PLZ,
        max( CASE WHEN pm.meta_key = 'billing_address_1' and p.ID = pm.user_id THEN pm.meta_value END ) as Strasse,     
        max( CASE WHEN pm.meta_key = 'billing_city' and p.ID = pm.user_id THEN pm.meta_value END ) as Ort,
        max( CASE WHEN pm.meta_key = 'kennung_produzent' and p.ID = pm.user_id THEN pm.meta_value END ) as Kennung

from
    wp_users p 
    join wp_usermeta pm on p.ID = pm.user_id
where  
    pm.meta_value = 'Prod'
group by
    p.ID
```

Comment: you want to show all  wp_usermeta columns? and what's mean ( mw )?

Comment: Please provide example of return you expect, because your explanation is unclear. If you want only value of `kennung_produzent` you may delete all other columns.

Comment: It would be helpful if you added sample data and expected output as text to the question.

Comment: and p.ID = pm.user_id isn't useful that's already achieved by the join

Comment: Thank you all for your answers.

Sorry mw = me (

Here are the expected output

| ID | user_login | user_registered| display_name | nickname | billing-email | billing_first_name | billing_last_name | billing_phone | billing_postcode | billing_adress_1 | billing_city | kennung_produzent |

Here are a data example

| 40 | MariaF |  2019-11-17 13:18 | Maria Mustermann | maria | maria.mustermann@gmx.at | Maria | Musterfrau | 5202 | 0043222456789 | Hauptstr. 30 | Neumarkt | Prod 

I have 50 lines in the table. 5-6 of this lines have 'Prod' in the column Kennung_produzent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to filter the result to only the ones for which in `wp_usermeta` there is row with `meta_key='kennung_produzent'` and `meta_value = 'Prod'`

What that query is doing is different, because you are filtering by `pm.meta_value = 'Prod'` so you are removing all the rows because it also expects the value to be Prod when `pm.meta_key = 'billing_email'`, and when 
`pm.meta_key = 'nickname'` and so on.

Not knowing your data, and based on your last comment, assuming you have more than one row per user with meta_key="kennung_produzent" , I would say that what you want to do is more similar to

```
select * from (

SELECT p.ID,
       p.user_login,
       p.user_registered,
       p.display_name,
        max( CASE WHEN pm.meta_key = 'nickname' and p.ID = pm.user_id THEN pm.meta_value END ) as Nickname,
        max( CASE WHEN pm.meta_key = 'billing_email' and p.ID = pm.user_id THEN pm.meta_value END ) as email,
        max( CASE WHEN pm.meta_key = 'billing_first_name' THEN pm.meta_value END ) as Vorname,
        max( CASE WHEN pm.meta_key = 'billing_last_name' THEN pm.meta_value END ) as Nachname,
        max( CASE WHEN pm.meta_key = 'billing_phone' THEN pm.meta_value END ) as Telefon,
        max( CASE WHEN pm.meta_key = 'billing_postcode'  THEN pm.meta_value END ) as PLZ,
        max( CASE WHEN pm.meta_key = 'billing_address_1' THEN pm.meta_value END ) as Strasse,     
        max( CASE WHEN pm.meta_key = 'billing_city' THEN pm.meta_value END ) as Ort,
        max( CASE WHEN pm.meta_key = 'kennung_produzent' THEN pm.meta_value END ) as Kennung

from
    wp_users p 
    join wp_usermeta pm on p.ID = pm.user_id
group by
    p.ID

) a

where Kennung LIKE "Prod"
```

the performance of this query can be very bad, but please let me know if it does what you need so at least we have a starting point

Comment: Hi,Thank you but it shows me now all lines of the table. I would need only the lines where the meta.value of the meta.key 'Kennung_produzent'  = 'Prod'.

Comment: Here are the expected output

| ID | user_login | user_registered| display_name | nickname | billing-email | billing_first_name | billing_last_name | billing_phone | billing_postcode | billing_adress_1 | billing_city | kennung_produzent |

Here are a data example

| 40 | MariaF |  2019-11-17 13:18 | Maria Mustermann | maria | maria.mustermann@gmx.at | Maria | Musterfrau | 5202 | 0043222456789 | Hauptstr. 30 | Neumarkt | Prod |

Comment: Only a few lines fromm 50 lines have *Prod' in the column 'Kennung_produzent'.

Comment: I added an update. Not sure if this is what you need since it is very hard without checking the real data

Comment: Hi Carlos, Yes this works fine. Thank you very much for your support. Best regards Siegfried (and stay healthy)

Comment: Good to know. Please @uebes upvote and accept the answer (that marks is as correct, to help other users, plus gives me with some some points) thanks!